# Android i taking picture using Intent

Tags: android

With this code i am able to take picture but in **onCreate() the name of image is static like "name.jpg" but when i change it to  new Date().toString()+".jpg"** it stops working...
Please help me to make the name of image dynamic according to the time of picture taken. 
Thanks

```
          public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.picturelayout);
        String imageName=new Date().toString();
        path=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/TrackMe/"+"name.jpg";
    }
    public void CLICK(View v)
    {
        File f=new File(path);

         Uri myuri=Uri.fromFile(f);
         Intent i =new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
         i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, myuri);
         startActivityForResult(i, 0);
    }
     public void back(View view){
         Intent intentBack=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SettingsActivity.class);
         startActivity(intentBack);
     }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(resultCode==0)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Photo not taken", 
Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else
        {
        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path); 
        ImageView iv=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.trackMePicture);
        iv.setImageBitmap(bm);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this,

For getting date value,

```
String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
```

Use this string to save

```
 path=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/TrackMe/"+"timeStamp.jpg"
```

Comment: Another problem is if TrackMe directory is not there then it is not saving the picture. The further code is:                               File f=new file(path); if (!f.exists()){ f.mkdirs();}

Comment: @user1414863: Why you are add this, you need to check if the directory is present or not?

Comment: yeap i am checking with !f.exists() f.mkdir() but it is not making directory. But when i manually create the directory with TrackMe name in device it works.

Comment: @user1414863: Try with this,   File file1 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/FolderName");
            if (!file1.exists())
            {
                file1.mkdirs();
            }

            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/FolderName/"+"ImageName"+".png");

Answer (score 1):

Generate Timestamp as

```
SimpleDateFormat s = new SimpleDateFormat("ddhhmmss");
format = s.format(new Date());
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss");
    String imageName = sdf.format(new Date());
    path=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/TrackMe/"+imageName+".jpg";
```